# One-to-many insert/upsert from landing to separate DE's

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, insert, preference-center

I'm bulding a preference center and having trouble with writing into two separate DE's.

We have two DE's:

1. Newsletter_Subscribers (EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, OptIn, Country, IPAddress, DateSubscribed, DateModified, DateUnsusbscribed)

Inserted here would be subscribers general data (only one row per subscriber).

2. Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics (RecordID(concat Email + TopicID), EmailAddress, TopicID, DateSubscribed, DateUnsubscribed
   In here would be every topic in.separate row based on a recordid.

What I'm having trouble with is to write Topics in a seperate DE row by row (PK is RecordID) - I can only get a flat insert

Has anybody tried this before?

Tnx.

Comment: I apologize but I am unsure what you mean. Do you mean you want to insert multiple records into a DE in one call?  If so, you can only do this via API or via a FOR loop that will then loop through each Topic and call the insert function once per topic - inserting multiple rows.

Comment: No need to apologize it my fault for writing my question so stupidly. I was trying to.post some code but it keeps breaking up so I wrote just the question. Yes that was exactly what I meant, general subscriber data in one DE, and topics in multiple rows by recordid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to level-set. There is no way in AMPscript to do a batch upload.  For those you would have to utilize a FOR loop and do multiple inserts.

For example:

```
%%[
  SET @newsSubsRes = InsertDE('Newsletter_Subscribers', 'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress, 'FirstName',@FirstName...etc...)

  FOR @i=1 to RowCount(@TopicRowset) DO

    SET @row = ROW(@TopicRowset,@i)
    SET @TopicID = FIELD(@row, 'TopicID')

    SET @newsTopicsRes = InsertDE('Newsletter_Subscribers_Topics', 'RecordID', CONCAT(@EmailAddress,@TopicID),'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'TopicID',@TopicID,...etc...)

  NEXT @i
]%%
```

This would do the single call for the Subscriber, and then loop through each of the topics you have (via `@TopicRowset`) and then inserts them into the DE one at a time.  If the number of topics is significant, this could run into performance issues though.

For SSJS you can do a CORE function [Rows.Add](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.htm) to push in a bulk insert.  I do warn though that with any significant volume, this can start to have a performance degredation.

```javascript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var arrContacts =  [];

for (i=0;i<topicArr.length;i++) {
    
    var obj = {}
    var TopicID = topicArr[i];

    var obj = {"RecordID": EmailAddress + TopicID, "EmailAddress": EmailAddress, "TopicID": TopicID, "FirstName": FirstName}

    arrContacts.push(obj);
}

var topicDE = DataExtension.Init("Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics ");
topicDE.Rows.Add(arrContacts);
</script>
```

Another option if you do not want to do multiple inserts is to utilize WSProxy to push your data into the DE:

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

/* Need to set your Subscribers variables here - e.g. EmailAddress, Firstname, etc. */
var EmailAddress = 'sample@sample.com',
    FirstName = 'Sample',
    topicArr = ["cats","dogs","ferrets"],
    custKey1 = 'Newsletter_Subscribers',
    custKey2 = 'Newsletter_Subscriber_Topics';

var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var insertArr = [];
var insertObj = {};

//This creates the object for Subscriber DE
insertObj.CustomerKey = custKey1;
insertObj.Properties = [
    {
        Name: 'EmailAddress',
        Value: EmailAddress
    },
    {
        Name: 'FirstName',
        Value: FirstName
    }
    /* Continue filling in properties here */
]


insertArr.push(insertObj)

for (i=0;i<topicArr.length;i++) {

    var topicID = topicArr[i];
    var insertObj = {};

    //This creates the objects for Topics DE
    insertObj.CustomerKey = custKey2;
    insertObj.Properties = [
        {
            Name: 'RecordID',
            Value: EmailAddress + topicID
        },
        {
            Name: 'EmailAddress',
            Value: EmailAddress
        },
        {
            Name: 'TopicID',
            Value: topicID
        },
        {
            Name: 'FirstName',
            Value: FirstName
        }
        /* Continue filling in properties here */
    ]

    insertArr.push(insertObj)
}


var options = {SaveOptions:[{'PropertyName':'*',SaveAction:'insertAdd'}]};
var res = api.updateBatch('DataExtensionObject',insertArr,options);

</script>
```

This will gather all of the records you want to insert (in this example, I used upsert) into an array (`insertArr`) and then via the `updateBatch()` function for WSProxy, it pushes them all into the appropriate DEs inside a single call.